# I send list of files from .net5 mvc project to .net5 api, but get only one file instead of the list of files

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5

I have two models as follows:

```
public class Category
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public List<CategoryDetail> CategoryDetails { get; set; }
}


public class CategoryDetail
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Url { get; set; }
  public IFormFile File { get; set; }
  public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

I can bind categorydetail model in .NET5 mvc with list of files. The problem is, I get only one file when it post to the .NET5 API. It seems to me that MultipartFormDataContent cannot bind multiple files when loop through each file.

The following code send post request to the API

```
var multiForm = new MultipartFormDataContent();
multiForm.Add(new StringContent(entity.Id), "Id");
multiForm.Add(new StringContent(Convert.ToString(entity.Name)), "Name");

**foreach (var item in entity.CategoryDetails)
{
  int i = 0;
  multiForm.Add(new StringContent(item.Url), 
 "CategoryDetails[" + i + "].Url");
  multiForm.Add(new StreamContent(item.File.OpenReadStream()), 
 "CategoryDetails[" + i + "].File", item.File.FileName);
  i++;
}**

 var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url) { Content = multiForm };

 var accessToken = _context.HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => 
 c.Type==AppClaims.AccessToken)?.Value;
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
 {
   request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
 }

 var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("ApiServer");
 var response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Api Controller Function as follows:

```
    [RequestSizeLimit(2147483648)]
    [HttpPost("add")]
    [Consumes(@"application/octet-stream", @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "multipart/form-data")]
    [ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(BaseResponse))]

    public async Task<IActionResult> AddCategorySection([FromForm] 
    Category model)
    {
    }
```

Comment: Show us your controller code of ApiServer

Comment: Are you sure you are fetching an array or did you properly use the attributes over the "receive" method ? You could share how you are receiving files from server

Comment: Api controller added @RomanMarusyk

Comment: Hi @FabriceT I use the same model as I declare in the mvc project and I am sure that the declaration is okay. I can add multiple files using this api through postman.

Comment: Why not querying a list of categories as argument

Comment: could you please explain a bit about "querying a list of categories as argument" @FabriceT

Comment: `public [...]([FromForm] 
    Category model)` but `public [...]([FromForm] 
    List<Category> model)` or for best chance you use `IList`

Comment: I cannot do that because there is a one to many relationship between two models. I have to send only one category information with list of files. @FabriceT

Comment: I see... do you use a custom json converter ? Did you receive the correct object from Postman ? Files are in binary or only references ? What are you getting from Postman ?

Comment: All object value is set properly, even I got multiple files when send it through postman. I only got one file when send it using the mentioned code.@FabriceT

Answer (score 0):

The above code will work correctly. I just wrongly initialize the increment variable inside the foreach loop and each time initialize to 0. The correct code is as follows-

```
int i = 0;
foreach (var item in entity.CategoryDetails)
{
  multiForm.Add(new StringContent(item.Url), 
  "CategoryDetails[" + i + "].Url");
  multiForm.Add(new StreamContent(item.File.OpenReadStream()), 
  "CategoryDetails[" + i + "].File", item.File.FileName);
  i++;
}
```